# In C++, I don't know why my function doesn't return result

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("1.inp");

class TreeNode {   
private:
    friend class Tree;
    int Keyvalue;
    string Namevalue;
    TreeNode *LeftChild; 
    TreeNode *RightChild;

    TreeNode() { LeftChild = RightChild = 0; };
    TreeNode(int _Keyvalue, string _Namevalue, TreeNode *Lefty, TreeNode *Righty) {
        Keyvalue = _Keyvalue;
        Namevalue = _Namevalue;
        LeftChild = Lefty;
        RightChild = Righty;
    }
};

class Tree {
private:
    TreeNode *root; 
    void insert_to_tree(TreeNode *, int, string);
    void show_tree(TreeNode *);
public:
    Tree() { root = 0; }
    void insert_to_tree(int, string);
    void delete_from_tree(int);
    void show_tree();
    void setup();
};

void Tree::insert_to_tree(int _Keyvalue, string _Namevalue){
    insert_to_tree(root, _Keyvalue, _Namevalue);
}
//this is problem.
void Tree::insert_to_tree(TreeNode *CurrentNode, int _Keyvalue, string _Namevalue){
    if (CurrentNode == 0)
        CurrentNode = new TreeNode(_Keyvalue, _Namevalue, 0, 0);
    else{
        if (CurrentNode->Keyvalue < _Keyvalue)
            insert_to_tree(CurrentNode->RightChild, _Keyvalue, _Namevalue);
        else if (CurrentNode->Keyvalue == _Keyvalue)
            CurrentNode->Namevalue = _Namevalue;
        else
            insert_to_tree(CurrentNode->LeftChild, _Keyvalue, _Namevalue);
    }
}

void Tree::delete_from_tree(int _Keyvalue){
}

void Tree::show_tree(){
    show_tree(root);
}
void Tree::show_tree(TreeNode *CurrentNode){
    if (CurrentNode){
        if (CurrentNode->LeftChild == 0 && CurrentNode->RightChild == 0){
            cout << CurrentNode->Namevalue;
        }
        else{
            show_tree(CurrentNode->LeftChild);
            show_tree(CurrentNode->RightChild);
        }
    }
}

void get_command(Tree &_MyTree){
    int Num_of_command;
    string command;
    fin >> Num_of_command;
    for (int i = 0; i < Num_of_command; i++){
        fin >> command;
        int Keyvalue;   string Namevalue;
        if (command == "ins"){
            fin >> Keyvalue >> Namevalue;
            _MyTree.insert_to_tree(Keyvalue, Namevalue);
        }
        else if (command == "del"){
            fin >> Keyvalue;
            _MyTree.delete_from_tree(Keyvalue);
        }
        else if (command == "leaves")
            _MyTree.show_tree();
    }
}

int main(){
    Tree MyTree;
    get_command(MyTree);
}
```

When I call the function

```
void Tree::insert_to_tree(int _Keyvalue, string _Namevalue){
    insert_to_tree(root, _Keyvalue, _Namevalue); }
```

root isn't changed by my function. After the function

```
void Tree::insert_to_tree(TreeNode *CurrentNode, int _Keyvalue, string _Namevalue)
```

root is always 0.

Comment: Change the function signature to `void Tree::insert_to_tree(TreeNode*& CurrentNode, int _Keyvalue, string _Namevalue)`

Comment: You might consider to change the title. Your function is `void` which would be the simple answer to the question stated in the title, but I think this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to add - when you creating some node, it no inserting to you tree, just creating and losting it in memory. You should create nodes in way such if (CurrentNode->RightChild == NULL) CurrentNode->RightChild = new TreeNode(_Keyvalue, _Namevalue, 0, 0);

Comment: I think using * and & together will be offset. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing root by value - which means, your function sees a copy of `root`. Whatever it does to it, doesn't affect the original.

Consider the following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x) {
    x = 10;
}

int main() {
   int k = 42;
   foo(k);

   std::cout << "k is now " << k << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

If you run this code, you will see that k remains unchanged and is still printed as 42. This is because `foo()` modified the copy of k, and this did not touch original k.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new `TreeNode` but you never insert it into the tree or return the created `TreeNode` anywhere.

You probably mean to pass the `CurrentNode` by reference (`TreeNode *& CurrentNode`) which means that any changes made to it inside the functions will be seen outside the functions.